# merge (combine) fields from a query

Tags: mongodb, merge, database

This is the result of my query :

```
{
   id : 1 ,
   name : "Richard" ,
   last_name : "stallman",
   sex : "Mr"
}
```

But I need something like this :

```
{
   id : 1 ,
   details : "Mr Richard - stallman" 
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
db.COLLECTION.aggregate([{$project: {id: "$id", details: {$concat: ["$sex", " ", "$name", " ", "$last_name"]} }}])
```

See the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/ .

Comment: An even more detailed example there : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-computed-fields

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are querying a database?

You would have to query for the data, store it in variables, and then generate your new data.

i.e.

```
$details=row['sex']." ".row['firstname']." - ".rpw['lastname'];
```